# How to jQuery Validate the ReCaptcha?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

Recaptcha form is like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {"theme":"red","lang":"en"};
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeThAsTAAAAAKYRjSpA8XZ1s4izK65hYr9ulCiD">
    </script><noscript>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LeThAsTAAAAAKYRjSpA8XZ1s4izK65hYr9ulCiD"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0">                </iframe><br>
       <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
       </textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
       value="manual_challenge">
       </noscript>`

and validator of ZF2 for ReCaptcha is like this:

```html
 $recaptcha = new ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(PUB_KEY, PRIV_KEY);
 $html = $recaptcha->getHTML();
 $result = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);
 if (!$result->isValid()) {
  // invalid
 } else {
 // valid
 }
```

is it possible to validate it remotely like this: https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

I tried below in remote php file and it doesn't work:

```html
$recaptcha = new ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(PUB_KEY, PRIV_KEY);
$result = $recaptcha->verify($_GET['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_GET['recaptcha_response_field']);
if (!$result->isValid()) {
echo json_encode(false);
} else {
echo json_encode(true);
}
```

and js itself is:

```html
$().ready(function() {
$("#contact").validate({
                      rules: {
                               recaptcha_response_field: {
                                          required: true,
                                          remote: "json.php"
                               }             
                  }   
 });
 });
```

is it possible at all or I did something wrong?

Comment: As per jQuery docs, `$().ready(function()` is not recommended.   Use `$(document).ready(function()` instead.  Also, what troubleshooting have you done?   Is `json.php` at the correct location and being called?   Are you examining the Ajax call with your console?  Also, unless you use the `data` option of `remote`, you are only sending the value of the `recaptcha_response_field` to your PHP script.

Comment: Since other fields of the same form is validate remotely with the same json.php fine, I assume it is called. I'll try your edition and check with console.

Comment: How to use data option and how to send recaptcha_challlenge_field too? @Sparky

Comment: Also describe *"does not work"* in detail.

Comment: See example in jQuery Validate docs which shows how to use `data` option.

Comment: "does not work" I meant the form will be submitted if other fields validated. The same js/php catches other invalid fields fine except recaptcha, so I believe the problem should be recaptcha_challenge_field as you said. How to use data option and hos to send this value too?

Comment: See my previous comment.  Look at jQuery Validate website docs.  There is a whole page dedicated to `remote`, which contains an example using `data` option.

Comment: I tried what you said, it seems it works but after submit it gives error on server-side validation. So I guess when it was checked by ajax, a new captcha is generated that is invisible on page and the old one is on page so it gives wrong captcha after form submission. It seems ajax check of ReCaptcha is impossible if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Not impossible.  But you're right.  The captcha  code refreshes and you can't submit.   You might be able to do it by putting an Ajax check within the `submitHandler` option.  Search SO for this approach.

Comment: Please give some example.

Comment: I know similar has been achieved with the `submitHandler` callback.   Like I already said, search SO for this.

Comment: I am not understanding the difference? If on SubmitHandler it is wrong then the captcha won't be refreshed and invisible on page like previous problem? It won't be refreshed on every validation?

Comment: If captcha code fails, then you use the JavaScript provided by Google to programmatically refresh it without reloading page.  The other advantage of using `submitHandler` is that it only gets fired when the form is valid, leaving captcha as the last thing user deals with.  Again, check out the other SO answers that handle it like this.

Answer (score 0):

try this function to validate recaptcha

```
var grecaptchaId;
        var onloadCallback = function () {
            grecaptchaId = grecaptcha.render('grecaptcha', {
                'sitekey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'callback': function (response) {
                    $("#grecaptcha_error").text('');
                }
            });
        };

        function ValidateRecaptcha() {
            var x;
            x = grecaptcha.getResponse(grecaptchaId);
            if (x != "") {
                $("#grecaptcha_error").text('');
                return true;
            }
            else {
                $("#grecaptcha_error").text('The captcha is required and can\'t be empty');
                return false;
            }
        }
```